# ACF true/false field in a custom dashboard widget?

Tags: widgets, advanced-custom-fields, dashboard

I have a true/false ACF field a setting on my site. I was thinking that instead of burying it in an options page I could create a dashboard widget so it can be toggled on and off right from the main dashboard view. I have my dashboard widget registered and added to the dashboard, but I'm not sure how I can add the true/false toggle to it (or if that's even possible).

Here's my custom widget code:

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'custom_dashboard_widget');
  
function custom_dashboard_widget() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    
    wp_add_dashboard_widget('my_acf_setting', 'My Widget Title', 'acf_setting_widget');
}
 
function acf_setting_widget() {
    echo '<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>';
}
```